# HTTP Status 404 Spring MVC error on running controller

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets, tomcat7

I'm not able to run the controller in Spring MVC tomcat 7.0.56 as it shows "**HTTP Status 404 error**" everytime. Spring MVC can run welcome.jsp inside WEB-INF but not the path from the controller ie. '**/hello**'. I've checked several posts from SO to figure out this yet no luck. What am I doing wrong here? below are my codes :

**Project Structure:**

[image]

**web.xml**

```
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**SpringMVC-servlet.xml**

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.spring"></context:component-scan>

   <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
   <mvc:annotation-driven />

   <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

   <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>
   </beans>
```

**springController.java**

```
 package org.spring;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    @Controller
    public class SpringController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloworld() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("welcome");
        return model;
    }
    }
```

**welcome.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome Page</title>
</head>
<body>
Welcome to Spring MVC
</body>
</html>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.springMVC</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringMVC</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringMVC Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.2.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringMVC</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Remove `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` and add `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

Comment: I added and still doesn't work. I've made changes in my question above.

Comment: remove welcome-file-list, and change mapping like this @RequestMapping(value = {"/","/hello"})

Comment: I removed welcome-file-list and changed mapping like @RequestMapping(value = {"/","/hello"}) still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

change your `SpringMVC-servlet.xml` file put below code

```
     <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
        </bean>
     <context:component-scan base-package="org.spring"/>
     <mvc:annotation-driven/>


    @RequestMapping(value = {"/","/index","/hello"})
    public ModelAndView helloworld() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("welcome");
    return model;
}
```